# Core Plot momentum scrolling

Tags: iphone, graph, uiscrollview, scroll, core-plot

Is there any way I can make the Core Plot scrolling behave like momentum scrolling in UIScrollView? I have made a CPTGraphHostingView and added it to a UIViewController.view as a subview.

Would someone be kind enough to provide a direction or code to guide me through?

Answer (score 6):

Since Release 1.3, in [`CPTXYPlotSpace`](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/interface_c_p_t_x_y_plot_space.html), there is a flag called [`allowsMomentum`](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/interface_c_p_t_x_y_plot_space.html#a9fdd1c2961b64bfac4fcc37382f1d2a2):

> If `YES`, plot space scrolling slows down gradually rather than stopping abruptly. Defaults to `NO`.

So, you can do something like this:

```
CPTGraph* graph = /* Your graph object */
CPTXYPlotSpace* plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace*)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsMomentum = YES;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a WWDC 2012 presentation 'Enhancing User Experience with Scroll Views' which explains how to invisibly overlay a UIScrollView on a OpenGL view then link the scolloffset to get the momentum scrolling behaviour in OpenGL. I expect a similar approach could be used for your problem.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=223

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like that built in. You might be able to achieve a similar effect using a plot space delegate.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, can you give me a hints on how it can be done? Since I only deal with core plot for 1-2 weeks. How is momentum scrolling calculated?